# MemoryError when using requests_cache (with sqlite backend) inside Celery worker

Tags: python, sqlite, python-requests, celery

I have `requests-cache==1.1.0` and `celery==5.3.4` installed on M1 MacBook.

Nothing special about the config on either, but posting here just incase its somehow helpful

Celery config:

```
broker_url="redis://localhost",
result_backend="redis://localhost",
task_ignore_result=True,
```

Cached session config:

```
CachedSession("http_cache.db")
```

Whenever I try to run a celery task that makes a get request via `CachedSession` I get the following error:

```
File "***/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/sqlite.py", line 294, in __getitem__
    cur = con.execute(f'SELECT value FROM {self.table_name} WHERE key=?', (key,))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
MemoryError
```

From the debugger right before the line above I see:

```
(Pdb) self.table_name
'responses'
(Pdb) key
'32805c2791b85726'
(Pdb) con.execute(f'SELECT value FROM {self.table_name} WHERE key=?', (key,))
*** MemoryError
```

I cant execute any other queries on the connection either

```
(Pdb) con.execute('SELECT * FROM sqlite_master')
*** MemoryError
```

The task runs when I execute it directly in a shell, but when it gets run through celery worker it runs into the `MemoryError` when trying to execute on the connection.

The task also runs fine when I use regular `requests` or when I change the backend to `Redis` for example.

I am hoping to use the `Sqlite` backend as I need to indefinitely persist the responses. I have a feeling I can switch to `Mongo` backend and not have this issue but wanted to post it here before I commit to adding that dependency.

Really lost on this one, any ideas?

Comment: can you also post the python code,

Comment: I can post celery configuration and cached session. Its a large application spanning across files

Comment: it is only necessary connection string(sanitized) and definition  of cursor, also table structure would also help

Comment: The table structure is generated by `requests-cache`, its not custom. I am not saving or reading any models I created. The error is happening inside the package https://github.com/requests-cache/requests-cache/blob/main/requests_cache/backends/sqlite.py#L311

Comment: Might just open an issue on Github

Comment: Out of curiosity - why you use SQLite when you already use Redis (as backend)?? Why did you not simply use Redis for your CachedSession? ( https://github.com/requests-cache/requests-cache/blob/main/requests_cache/backends/redis.py ) Redis is _made_ for this purpose! Ofc, you just make sure you do not use the same Redis DB for both backend and requests-cache...

Comment: Yeah, that is also a great option. I ended up just building out a custom Postgres backend and it works great. The more I think about it the more silly it seems to even try using SQLite with Celery. it's just that the error is a bit misleading so I went down a bit of a rabbit hole

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging I think it has to do with the lock here: https://github.com/requests-cache/requests-cache/blob/main/requests_cache/backends/sqlite.py#L249. The error `MemoryError` is misleading.

Setting `--pool threads` when running Celery solves the issue, but probably just not trying to use Sqlite with Celery is the way to go.